# Database vs File

Tags: mysql, database, file, file-io

I've more than 60M tuples in a table. I need to retrieve each of the tuples. And after doing some operations, I need to insert  output corresponding to each tuple into database. What is the best way to do it? Which one will be efficient: retrieving tuples through query or writing them into file/files first, then reading them one by one?

Comment: Sorry but your question is very unclear.  _"60M tuples in a table"_ - what do you mean by "table" here? A database table? A CSV file? Something else?  When you process the tuples do you need to select a subset or are you always processing the entire file sequentially?

Comment: The data is in a database table. I need just one tuple at a time.

Comment: Just read the tuples with a query.

Answer (score -1):

File IO is relatively slow than database operations. So it is better to use a table instead of a flat file.